# getting the element of array while performing Euclidian calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and numpy. I have to calculate the Euclidean distance between two points. My first point is randomly generated and say

`x1[35,60]`

`x2= [[35 60]][[26 84][69 67][80 63][11 96][44 22][17 76][57 95][44 81][10 56][29 33]]`

I have successfully calculated the minimum Euclidean distance = 22.847 and found out the minimum Euclidean distance is between two points x1[35,60] and x2 [44,81]. But I found this out by printing the values and looking it manually. I want to store x2 (which ever gives the min Euclidean distance) in some variable so that i can use it later. How do I achieve this?

This is my code

from random import randint as r
    import numpy 
    from math import hypot

```
x = r(1, 100)
y = r(1, 100)
isFailedTest = (5<=x<=15) and (10<=y<=11)
selected_test = []
selected_test.append ((x,y))
candidate = [ (r(1,100), r(1,100)) for i in xrange(10)]    

x1= numpy.array(selected_test)
x2= numpy.array(candidate)

dists = numpy.hypot(x1[:, 0, numpy.newaxis]-x2[:, 0], x1[:, 1, numpy.newaxis]-x2[:, 1]) 
mindist = numpy.min(dists, axis=1)
minid   = numpy.argmin(dists, axis=1)

print mindist
print candidate
print x1
print x2
print minid
```

I think I am almost there as I can see the point which actually gave minimum distance by printing output. But I am not being able to access the point which gave minimum value programmatically. Any help suggestion/recommendation is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close to being done I'm not sure it can be fairly said that there is a problem left to solve here.

`minid` already contains the index of the candidate that has the minimum distance to the point `x1`, so you just have to

```
print candidate[minid[0]]
```

to display the best candidate.

Comment: Thanx. I got the value.